# Automatic email report generation potential?

Tags: email, reporting-services, visual-studio-2015, sql-server-2014

I'm doing some research on SSRS with sql server 2014, and I have a few questions I'd like answered if possible before I commit to using this solution (and I don't really have any other plausible ideas in mind...).

**The problem:** My small company has information stored on a database (SqlServer-2014 Enterprise x64). The database is not allowed to interact/display anything directly to the internet (web page or any other direct media for security reasons). Upper management has a road trip coming up and they would like a way to view day to day operational information (ONLY number of orders placed and what the top 10 most ordered items are) on the road. *The issue is that each and every one of them uses Ipads/Iphones.* I know virtually nothing about development on Apple products. I have developed applications only for Windows OS, and I'm not looking to learn how to develop on a Mac (for now... Ugh).

**Solution I came up with:** Use SSRS to automatically generate a timed email report (say every day at 6am and noon this report will be sent through email) with non-sensitive information (total # of orders, the top 10 most ordered items in a certain time-frame. Nothing with customer names, addresses, billing info etc.). The advantage of this solution is obvious - platform independence.

A slight twist I'm having some issue resolving through my research is... Is it possible for this type of report generation to be event driven as well as on a schedule? Specifically, I was thinking if there is an email sent to an email address (the email address would specifically be used for this purpose, nothing else. It would be this process's email address alone), could that be used to generate the report at any time the server's email address gets an email in it's inbox, and reply to whoever emailed the server's address with the *#of orders/top 10 most ordered item* - metrics? I haven't been able to find information on this yet, but I am lurking around the web working on it still... Any tutorials or informative sources you guys know about would be great.

**Quandary 1:** The main issue that causes me to hesitate using this method is a snippet from https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb153684(v=sql.120).aspx :
"To prevent the unintended execution of malicious code, Management Studio cannot be configured to automatically run a report, even if the file system is configured to associate .rdl files with Management Studio. Reports cannot be programmatically executed in Management Studio and cannot run from the command line through Management Studio." This applies to only Management Studio configured reports, correct? Then the server itself is fully capable of generating the report and delivering it in email form... right? **Quandary 1: SOLVED. Nevermind.**

**Quandary 2:** Edit: Removed - I figured it out. This process will not be a drain on our system resources. **SOLVED. Nevermind.**

**Quandary 3: (Optional)** I am not opposed to scrapping this solution if I find a better one. Has anyone had to deal with a cross-platform windows to mac issue? A second possibility is to have the ipad/iphone connect via VPN to acquire the information. The thing I dislike about this idea is I need to create something on the Apple product that can receive and display this information... which requires development on a mac... You see where this is going.

As pretty much the solo IT guy here (at least, the only one that can deal with this...), I appreciate all of SO's input and ideas. Thanks a lot.

Comment: I think the easiest solution is design, develop and deploy the report to Report Server and schedule subscriptions to delivery the report via Email in MHT to avoid different presentation across apps and formats. However if you get to connect the IOS devices to your network via VPN (or any) you can use [Datazen](https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/datazen/id604097486?mt=8) since you have Enterprise Edition you can use this great app to present to your users awesome visualizations and give them interactivity with data.

Comment: Thank Alejandro, I have never heard of Datazen before but I will check it out! It sounds ideal for my situation. I will report back what I find, or if I have questions about Datazen hopefully I can ask them to you here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did some similar solutions like your case before, so here is my thought

Because you have Enterprise edition of the SQL Server, you can set up the reporting server and create reporting subscription to send the report as email to the end users

There are two subscription types in SSRS: time driven or data driven. So if you want to have event driven, you need to build something to trigger the event. In my past design, I used Exchange Web Service in SSIS script task to scan service account mail box on a timely basis, if certain conditions met (email subject, attachment, etc.), the task will execute the reporting subscription.

I don't know how is your company's security policy defined "*The database is not allowed to interact/display anything directly to the internet*". But you can try

1. set up SSRS in form authentication mode, or create a site to wrap RS
   reports so user can access via user name and password
2. custom SSRS page to support different browsers

Comment: It's a bit of a mystery to myself. Quite a while before my time here, there was some type of cyber attack (I can't find out what type, no one knows) so there is a phobia over such things or doing anything which may increase the chance of one. I know how to secure such things, but the orders from the top say do nothing like that. The top is not very... informed about all things computer related... but boss says no, I gotta listen... Thank you for the suggestion, I'll report back how I did and such shortly.

Comment: Thanks for the help all, but until I can convince others to understand there is such a thing as being TOO secure (stripping away a lot of server functionality for security) I'm just going to create an excelmacro file, update the excel file periodically and automatically load it into OneDrive.

Comment: Well I understand sometimes it could be difficult to convince management board, but from any security practice Excel Macro is not a secured method. If possible, consider VSTO to create excel addin at least.